# What Is The Best Python Zip Module To Handle Large Files?

Tags: python, performance, compression, zip, extract

EDIT: Specifically compression and extraction speeds.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: have you compared the performance of zipfile to that of using zip/unzip directly in the shell?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997910/python-unzip-tremendously-slow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930445/fast-zip-decryption-in-python

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I made a random-ish large zipfile:

```
$ ls -l *zip
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  5000  115749854 Nov 18 19:16 large.zip
$ unzip -l large.zip | wc
   23396   93633 2254735
```

i.e., 116 MB with 23.4K files in it, and timed things:

```
$ time unzip -d /tmp large.zip >/dev/null

real    0m14.702s
user    0m2.586s
sys         0m5.408s
```

this is the system-supplied commandline unzip binary -- no doubt as finely-tuned and optimized as a pure C executable can be.  Then (after cleaning up /tmp;-)...:

```
$ time py26 -c'from zipfile import ZipFile; z=ZipFile("large.zip"); z.extractall("/tmp")'

real    0m13.274s
user    0m5.059s
sys         0m5.166s
```

...and this is Python with its standard library - a bit more demanding of CPU time, but over 10% faster in real, that is, elapsed time.

You're welcome to repeat such measurements of course (on your specific platform -- if it's CPU-poor, e.g a slow ARM chip, then Python's extra demands of CPU time may end up making it slower -- and your specific zipfiles of interest, since each large zipfile will have a very different mix and quite possibly performance).  But what this suggests to me is that there isn't that much space to build a Python extension much faster than good old `zipfile` -- since Python using it beats the pure-C, system-included unzip!-)

Comment: Thanks for your analysis, it's has been most helpful.

Comment: It would be nice to see memory usage measurements too. +1 anyway.

Comment: Apparently, your mileage may vary... http://dmarkey.com/wordpress/2011/10/15/python-zipfile-speedup-tips/

Answer (score 5):

For handling large files without loading them into memory, use the new stream-based methods in Python 2.6's version of `zipfile`, such as `ZipFile.open`. **Don't** use `extract` or `extractall` unless you have strongly sanitised the filenames in the ZIP.

(You used to have to `read` all the bytes into memory, or hack around it like [zipstream](http://www.doxdesk.com/software/py/zipstream.html); this is now obsolete.)

Comment: I found opening compressed content on the fly with `zipfile.open()` to be actually slightly _faster_ than opening the same number of files from the file system (i.e. extracted previously from a .zip archive). This is probably because `zipfile.open()` uses the already open .zip and does not require the overhead of file system directory and file open operations. Disclaimer: I had to process many small files with a weak compression ratio. YMMV with bigger files or when there are not so many files in the archive. I used Python 3.5.3.