# efficiently read one file from a zip containing a lot of files in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, unzip, zip

I am storing an index in a compressed zip on disk and wanted to extract a single file from this zip. Doing this in python seems to be very slow, is it possible to solve this.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("testoutput/index_doc.zip", mode='r') as myzip:
    with myzip.open("c0ibtxf_i.txt") as mytxt:
        txt = mytxt.read()
        txt = codecs.decode(txt, "utf-8")
        print(txt)
```

Is the python code I use. Running this script in python takes a noticably long time

```
python3 testunzip.py  1.22s user 0.06s system 98% cpu 1.303 total
```

Which is annoying, especially since I know it can go much faster:

```
unzip -p testoutput/index_doc.zip c0ibtxf_i.txt  0.01s user 0.00s system 69% cpu 0.023 total
```

as per request: profiling

```
Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.051    0.051    1.492    1.492 <string>:1(<module>)
127740    0.043    0.000    0.092    0.000 cp437.py:14(decode)
     1    0.000    0.000    1.441    1.441 testunzip.py:69(toprofile)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:72(RLock)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 utf_8.py:15(decode)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:1065(__enter__)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:1068(__exit__)
     1    0.692    0.692    1.441    1.441 zipfile.py:1085(_RealGetContents)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:1194(getinfo)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:1235(open)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:1591(__del__)
     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:1595(close)
     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:1713(_fpclose)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:191(_EndRecData64)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:234(_EndRecData)
127739    0.180    0.000    0.220    0.000 zipfile.py:320(__init__)
127739    0.046    0.000    0.056    0.000 zipfile.py:436(_decodeExtra)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:605(_check_compression)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:636(_get_decompressor)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:654(__init__)
     3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:660(read)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:667(close)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:708(__init__)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:821(read)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:854(_update_crc)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:901(_read1)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:937(_read2)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 zipfile.py:953(close)
     1    0.000    0.000    1.441    1.441 zipfile.py:981(__init__)
127740    0.049    0.000    0.049    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.charmap_decode}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.decode}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.utf_8_decode}
127743    0.058    0.000    0.058    0.000 {built-in method _struct.unpack}
127739    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {built-in method builtins.chr}
     1    0.000    0.000    1.492    1.492 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
255484    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.min}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method io.open}
     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method zlib.crc32}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {function ZipExtFile.close at 0x101975620}
127741    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
127740    0.224    0.000    0.317    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'bytes' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
127739    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
     7    0.006    0.001    0.006    0.001 {method 'read' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
510956    0.071    0.000    0.071    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.BytesIO' objects}
     8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'seek' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
     4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'tell' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
```

it seems to be something that happens in the constructor? Can I avoid this overhead somehow?

Comment: which part is slow? (run a profiler). What happens if you run `unzip` using `subprocess` module?

Comment: Maybe an import comment is that the first line seems to take quite a long time. it seems not to be the opening itself, but rather the creation of the zipfile.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian running unzip using subprocess goes equally fast as in terminal. Profile information added in question.

Comment: the profiler says that the most time is spent reading the table of contents for the zip file. Is it a large zip file with many files?

Comment: yes it is, around 128k files are in it. But how comes that the terminal-command doesn't need to read that table of contents?

Comment: It is just how ZipFile is implemented. It creates a `ZipInfo()` object for each file in the zip archive whether you read it later or not. `unzip` may skip creating unnecessary structs *and the corresponding IO* (I'm not sure; it depends on the zip format i.e., it might call a single `seek()` instead of ~300k `read()` calls) or perhaps it is just pure Python vs. C for simple operations (such as parsing a blob of memory as a structure)—C may be faster 100x times in such cases. Try a line profiler and focus on `_RealGetContents()` method, to see whether there are anomalies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111554/discussion-between-pinna-be-and-j-f-sebastian).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was:

- pythons zipfile library builds a list of information object for each file in the zip
- this causes zipfile to be quite fast once it's loaded.
- but when there are a lot of files in the zip and you only need a small portion of this files each time you load the zip, the overhead of creating the info-list costs a lot of time.

To solve this, I adapted the source of python's zipfile. It has all the default functionalities you need, but when you give the constructor a list of the filenames to extract, it will not build the entire information list.

In the particular use case that you only need a few files from a zip, this will make a big difference in performance and memory usage.

for the particular case in the example above (namely extracting only one file from a zip containing 128K files, the speed of the new implementation now approaches the speed of the unzip method)

A test case:

```
def original_zipfile(): 
    import zipfile  
    with zipfile.ZipFile("testoutput/index_doc.zip", mode='r') as myzip:
        with myzip.open("c6kn5pu_i.txt") as mytxt:
            txt = mytxt.read()

def my_zipfile():   
    import zipfile2
    with zipfile2.ZipFile("testoutput/index_doc.zip", to_extract=["c6kn5pu_i.txt"], mode='r') as myzip:
        with myzip.open("c6kn5pu_i.txt") as mytxt:
            txt = mytxt.read()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    time1 = time.time() 
    original_zipfile()
    print("running time of original_zipfile = "+str(time.time()-time1))
    time1 = time.time() 
    my_zipfile()
    print("running time of my_new_zipfile   = "+str(time.time()-time1))

    print(myStopwatch.getPretty())
```

resulted in the following time readings

```
running time of original_zipfile = 1.0871901512145996
running time of my_new_zipfile   = 0.07036209106445312
```

I will include the source code, but notice that there are 2 small flaws to my implementation (once you give an extract list, when you don't the behaviour will be the same as mentioned before):

1. it assumes all filenames to be encoded in the same encoding (which is an optimisation I included for my own purposes)
2. other functionality might be altered (for example extract_all might fail or only extract the files you gave to the the constructor)

[github link](https://github.com/ThomasPinna/python_zipfile_improvement/tree/master)

Comment: do you give me permission to include and adapt your code (of course I'll credit you in the header of your file)  in my lib Dikt ? It's a library to access dict-like object out of memory quickly.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but the full file `testoutput/index_doc.zip` needs to be loaded into memory in your solution before pulling `c6kn5pu_i.txt` from within it, right? If that is the case would you be able to advice how to load only the particular file without loading whole zip file into memory?

Comment: It's been a while, but I remember that the change I did was exactly to avoid loading the entire index!