# Python zip extraction very slow. Manual extraction is fast

Tags: python, zip, compression, extract

I am using the following code to download and extract a zip file ~250MB.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile
import traceback
import sys

data_path = os.path.join(".", "data")
Path(data_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # assuming Python >= 3.5
url_str = 'https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data_2018/UCRArchive_2018.zip'
zip_out_path = os.path.join(data_path, "UCRArchive_2018.zip")

if not os.path.exists(zip_out_path):
    try:
        print("starting to download dataset zip")
        file_content = requests.get(url_str, timeout=10, verify=False).content
    except requests.RequestException as ex:
        traceback.print_exc(ex)
        sys.stderr.write(r"Auto download failed. For manual download see ./zip_password.txt")
        raise
    print("downloaded dataset zip. Takes ~1min")
    print("writing zip.")
    with open(zip_out_path, 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(file_content)

print("extracting zip. Takes several minutes, manual is fast.")
with ZipFile(zip_out_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(data_path, pwd=b"someone")
print("done extracting.")
```

The file gets downloaded, but the extraction is **extremely** slow.

When manually extracting it (double click, extract), everything works fine.

**What is happening and how to fix this?**

Comment: Looks like the zipfile library is pure Python, so there's your reason right there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158648/faster-alternative-to-pythons-zipfile-module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997910/python-unzip-tremendously-slow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930445/fast-zip-decryption-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141286/efficiently-read-one-file-from-a-zip-containing-a-lot-of-files-in-python