# Python ZipFile Slow for big files, Need Alternatives

Tags: python-3.x, python-zipfile

I am using ZipFile in python to unzip a 6GB file. But it seems to be taking over 3hours to do so.
I need to find a better alternative to fit within 20mins. Below is the code i have been working with which works perfectly fine but is very slow.

Python: 3.8.8

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
str_zipFile = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Test.zip'
str_pwd= '1234'

with ZipFile(str_zipFile) as zipObj:
    zipObj.extractall(pwd = bytes(str_pwd,'utf-8'))
```

Please suggest a faster method.

Comment: You should try using python's `os` module to run the `zip` command in the system shell... Not sure whether that's not actually what ZipFile does, but if it doesn't it may be an alternative

Comment: Related to Jake's comment, you could try using 7zip with `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()`. My experience with 7zip awhile back was that it could be faster than the usual zip-file utilities.

Comment: Have you tested extraction with the typical tools? How long does that take?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it using a winzip or winrar it takes less than 5mins to unzip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997910/python-unzip-tremendously-slow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141286/efficiently-read-one-file-from-a-zip-containing-a-lot-of-files-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Quote from Python *zipfile* module [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html):

> Decryption is extremely slow as it is implemented in native Python rather than C.

To get better performance, you can invoke an external program like `unzip` or `7z`

Answer (score -1):

You could use `subprocess.call(['unzip',filename,'-p',password])`. This will call the unzip program that is used to expand zips. For more details: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip And don't forget to import the `subprocess` module!