# Performance issue in unzipping files using Python

Tags: python, performance, zip

I'm using this code for unzipping zipped password protected files:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(folder_name+'\\'+each+'\\'+latest, "r") as z:
        z.extractall(folder_name+'\\'+each+'\\'+each,pwd=passwd)
```

This functionally works perfect, but is very slow. Is there any way to make unzipping fast?

Comment: Buy a faster hard drive.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sir it is running on remote system whose hardware is not under my control.

Comment: How does it compare to using the zip utility from the command line? The numbers should be similar and that would suggest that you are I/O bound.

Comment: @tdelaney it is much slower than wizip

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997910/python-unzip-tremendously-slow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930445/fast-zip-decryption-in-python

Answer (score 5):

From the Python zipfile docs:

> It supports decryption of encrypted files in ZIP archives, but it
>   currently cannot create an encrypted file. Decryption is extremely
>   slow as it is implemented in native Python rather than C.

To speed up password protected unzipping - you should probably shell out to a separate utility.

Comment: For the record: the decompression is still done in C code; only metadata handling and decryption are done in Python code, and it is the decryption that is slow.